# Ionic app become blank after closing an inAppBrowser (landscape)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, ionic3

I have a view in an Ionic app that launches a InAppBrowser

```
    this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_blank');
```

On my iPad, the app become a complete blank after I press "done" at the bottom of the inAppBrowser

I can reproduce this on simulator:

1. Make sure device in landscape orientation
2. Launch inAppBrowser
3. Press done to close the InAppBrowser
4. App become blank.
5. Rotate app to portrait, app appears again.

What is happening?

**Other information:**
Happens on iPad Air 2 simulator, iOS 10.3

**Ionic info:**

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 4.1.1 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.6.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer from this bug report:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12436

Apparently the white screen is caused by status bar plugin.

I solved my problem by updating status bar plugin to 2.2.3

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue :) Please accept this answer when you can (I think it could be done in two days) so we can close the issue.